# Azure function with Servicebus how to not mark message as complete

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function that listens to messages in an Azure Servicebus queue. When it receives the messages it marks them as complete and they are no longer in the queue. 
Is there a way to mark them as only when a long process completes ? Or un mark them as complete if it fails ?

My function calls an Api and I would like the message to not be marked as complete till the Api responds back with a success code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message will be marked as complete after the function execution is complete.

The easiest way to abort the message is to throw an exception from your function, e.g. when your API responds with error status code. In this case, the message will be put back to the queue and the function will be re-tried (up until the max number of retries configured for this Service Bus queue).

Comment: From Microsoft: "The Functions runtime receives a message in PeekLock mode. It calls Complete on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls Abandon if the function fails. If the function runs longer than the PeekLock timeout, the lock is automatically renewed as long as the function is running." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior

Comment: V2. Runtime seems to restart the function host if an exception is raised - this also affects the AppInsights log of the error.

Comment: @DavidLapeš Yes, I've heard that a few days ago, which is very worrying. I hope they fix that.

Answer (score 20):

> When it receives the messages it marks them as complete and they are no longer in the queue.

By default, the Functions runtime actually doesn't mark a message as complete [until your function returns successfully](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---peeklock-behavior). As mentioned in the accepted answer, throwing an exception (in your case, if the API being called returns with an unfavorable response) would abandon the message and prevent it from being marked as complete.

For a lot more control over when your message is completed, abandoned, etc, you can consume your message as a [BrokeredMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage?view=azure-dotnet) type as mentioned previously. This class directly supports the methods you'd need to control what happens to your message. Note, the [service bus trigger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---usage) mentions that `BrokeredMessage` should be used for Azure Functions version **1.***. If you're using version **2.***, you should consume your message as a [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet) type instead.

One pain-point of using `Message` is that, unlike `BrokeredMessage`, it doesn't directly have methods to let you control when a message is completed, etc. To achieve this, we can bind a [MessageReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver?view=azure-dotnet) parameter to our function.

To show how this works, here's an dead-lettering example of using `Message` along with `MessageReceiver`:

```cs
[FunctionName("SOExampleFunction"]
public static async Task ProcessMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")] Message message,
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver)
{
    . . .

    await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

    . . .
}
```

While using this approach, make sure you have the "autoComplete" service bus setting set to false in your host.json. E.g.:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding that "autoComplete": false won't have any effect - the runtime will still try to complete the message, even if you have manually called .Complete() on it. That will then cause an exception to be thrown, because a message can't complete twice...

Comment: @radders you might be running into this  https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/34 The last comment helped resolve my issue

Comment: I'm using v1 and found that the MessageReceiver wasn't binding. Updating the message from a string to BrokeredMessage is what I had to do. The v1 docs mention using MessageReceiver but I just couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, if you set the signature of your function to accept accept a BrokeredMessage then you can manually deadletter a message.

```
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public async static Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage)]BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, TraceWriter log) {

    // This will immediately deadletter the message.
    await brokeredMessage.DeadLetterAsync("My reason for deadlettering", "Some description that further explains...");

    return;

}
```

Comment: this is basically for earlier version of service bus trigger. BrokeredMessage is now called Message. `MessageReceiver messageReceiver` is not possible to inject before thus BrokeredMessage should be used to call the `DeadLeterAsync`